# What is the probability of no 2 numbers being consecutive, if 5 numbers are randomly chosen from a set of 40 numbers?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

If you randomly choose 5 numbers between 1 and 40 (inclusive), what is the probability that no two of the 5 numbers are consecutive?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1422082/probability-consecutive-numbers

Comment: Another one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/490405/choosing-numbers-without-consecutive-numbers

Answer (score 2):

Try this physical model:

Take 5 black ball and 36 white balls (yes, a total of 41 balls!).

Glue each black ball to a white ball;  you now have 5 identical glued ball pairs, and 31 identical white balls.

Arrange the 36 items in a straight line, left to right;  ***always***  place a black-white pair with the black on the ***left***.

The position of each black ball, from left to right, indicates which numbers are to be selected.  The glued white balls prevent any adjacent black balls, and hence any consecutive pairs of numbers. The rules prevent Location #41 from holding a black ball

How many ways are there to arrange 36 items, with 5 identical to each other, and the other 31 identical?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

1. How many ways are there to choose any 5 numbers from 40 numbers?
2. How many ways are there to choose 5 numbers from a set of 40, if no 2 can be consecutive?
3. What is the desired probability?

Comment: I'm unsure how you would do 2.

Comment: @user2910074 Follow the link I gave you. The answer is there for you....

Comment: I have done, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: try using the inclusion exclusion principle.

Answer (score 0):

The denominator is the number of ways we can select $5$ of $40$ balls.

For the numerator:

Line up $35$ blue balls.  This creates $36$ gaps, $34$ between successive blue balls and the two ends of the row.  Select five of those $36$ gaps in which to place five green balls.  Now number the balls from left to right.