# The probability that the subset will have at least one neighbor present is

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> In a game of tickets,the tickets are marked $1,2,3,...,50$.If 6
>   unordered combination of tickets is selected,then the probability that
>   the subset will have at least one neighbor present is [if at the time
>   of starting the tickets are arranged in a specific order and kept in a
>   linear way] ?

What should be the correct approach?

Comment: I am not sure I understood the question correctly. Are you asking for the probability that among six different random tickets there are no consecutive tickets?

Comment: Its not my own question but from a maths test paper actually.But yeah, I guess that's what the question is asking for @JackD'Aurizio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may pick $\binom{50}{6}$ different sets of tickets. Any set of tickets without consecutive tickets can be mapped bijectively into a septuple $(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)$ such that $a,g\in\mathbb{N}$, $b,c,d,e,f\in\mathbb{N}^+$ and $a+b+c+d+e+f+g = 44$. By [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29), the number of sets of tickets without consecutive tickets equals the number of ways of writing $46$ as the sum of $7$ positive integers, i.e. $\binom{45}{6}$. It follows that the wanted probability is:

$$ \frac{\binom{45}{6}}{\binom{50}{6}}=\frac{45\cdot 44\cdot 43\cdot 42\cdot 41\cdot 40}{50\cdot 49\cdot 48\cdot 47\cdot 46\cdot 45}=\frac{19393}{37835}\approx \color{red}{51,257\%}.$$

Comment: Oh ok I got it now.Thanks to this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1476792/what-is-the-probability-of-no-2-numbers-being-consecutive-if-5-numbers-are-rand

Comment: typo, you don't want $g\in \mathbb{N}^+$

Comment: @snarfblaat: right, now fixed.